# Writing webpart but getting 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined error

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I am writing a webpart based on another webpart that works. I have copied everything but when I load the new version i get a "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined" error which does not show up in the original.
Its breaking here:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#NewsTicker').vTicker({
        speed: 500,
        pause: 3000,
        showItems: 1,
        animation: 'fade',
        mousePause: true,
        direction: 'up'
    });
});
```

I have references that exist to the jquery library within the collection:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/NewsTicker/Scripts/jquery.js" runat="server" />
```

no idea why my version is blowing up.

Comment: Are you added jQuery *before* this script tag?

Comment: No. the scriptlink is at the top of the asp page

Answer (score 0):

You could try disabling MDS (minimal download strategy) to check if this is the issue.  If it is, then typically your library may not be getting loaded when navigating between pages as only the changed parts of the page are loaded.